# Twitter app Callback always redirect to Localhost:1337

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-generate-auth

generate-oauth, and i configure my twitter Passport with consumer key and consumer Secret.

In my twitter App i configure my url callback, but when i login with twitter, it always redirect to localhost:1337, and not my callback url that i define in the configuration.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one was very annoying for me to track down as well, and far as I can tell was completely undocumented, but in `/api/services/passport.js` there is a variable called `baseUrl`. I believe it is set to `sails.app.url`.

Regardless of what it is set as, you should set it to your desired callback URL, this should solve the problem for you.